# ubuntu9.10 : how to use python's lib-dynload and site-packages directories?

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation

In ubuntu 9.10, in usr/lib/ there are the directories python2.4, python2.5, python2.6 and python3.0

Only python 2.6 is actually working.
python2.4 has only a lib-dynload directory,
python2.5 has only lib-dynload and site-packages,
python3.0 has only a dist-packages directory.

Now i'm wondering what is the idea behind this? 
Because when i install python2.5 with ./configure, make, make install | altinstall
this goes into usr/local/lib and not usr/lib/ so why were these directories added tu ubuntu, how am i supposed to install python to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

j3ll3, in Ubuntu (or any DPKG-based Linux OS) you can ask the question "**What package provides** XYZ" by typing

```
dpkg -S /path/to/XYZ
```

So, for example, in Ubuntu 9.10,

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/gdbm.so
```

returns

```
python-gdbm: /usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/gdbm.so
```

You can find out more about the python-gdbm package by typing

```
apt-cache show python-gdbm
```

which says that python-gdbm provides "GNU dbm database support for Python".
Perhaps more interestingly, if you type

```
dpkg --listfiles python-gdbm
```

you get to see a listing of all the files that python-gdbm installs:

```
...
/usr/lib/python2.4
/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload/gdbm.so
/usr/lib/python2.5
/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/gdbm.so
/usr/lib/python2.6
/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/gdbm.so
...
```

So it looks like this single package installs 3 .so libraries, one for each version of python.

Python2.6 is the default version of python in Ubuntu 9.10, but it is also possible to install 
python2.4, 2.5 and/or 3.0. Unless you do so, only /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/gdbm.so is used, the others are just wasting space.

Since the unneeded files in python2.4, 2.5, 3.0 are not very large, the package maintainer probably felt it was easier to ship one package rather than one for each version of python.

However, unless you know how to fix future apt-get errors, I'd recommend *not* manually deleting any files that were installed by packages in Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi ~unutbu,
this answers the first part of my question by explaining where those files came from. Awesome!

Comment: The second part of my question is answered by steveha. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like they're an accident from some package(s) you have installed.

The Python version in use determines the locations searched to find installed Python packages/modules, and the "system version" of Python in Ubuntu 9.10 is 2.6, so that's what practically everything should be using.  If you were to install the python2.5 package (or it gets installed as a dependency of something else), then it would use /usr/lib/python2.5/*.  Try running `which python` and `python --version`; also `which python2.6` and `which python2.5`.

From what I understand, though I'm not sure exactly why at all, Debian (from which Ubuntu is derived) uses a `dist-packages` naming scheme instead of `site-packages`.

**Terminology:** Python has packages and Debian (and so Ubuntu) has packages.  They aren't the same kind of package, though individual Debian packages will install specific Python packages.

Comment: Hi Roger, 
Thanks for taking the time.

"Sounds like they're an accident from some package(s) you have installed."

These packages were already there on  a clean install of ubuntu 9.10 so before i added any additional packages. They came with ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question: when you install packages from source, you should use the packages' `setup.py` installer to install them automatically and correctly.  This installer already knows where to properly install the modules so Python can find them.  To use, simply call with the exact Python interpreter you want to use the package with.

A crash course in `setup.py`.  First, run it with the exact Python executable that you want the package to be available to.  If you want to use the package with `/usr/bin/python2.5`, you should use `/usr/bin/python2.5` to run `setup.py`.  Second, go to the directory where that package's `setup.py` is installed.  Third, you must install as root, so it's easiest to do the whole tihng as root.  Fourth, if you want to install to multiple Python interpreters, you should run `setup.py` with each, but you should clean it in between.  So here's what I would do:

```
% cd /root/directory/of/untarred/source/package
% sudo su
# /path/to/first/python setup.py build install
# rm -rf build
# /path/to/second/python setup.py build install
# rm -rf build
# exit
%
```

If you're installing modules by hand... you shouldn't, you should use its `setup.py`.  (If you wrote a new module, you should write a `setup.py` for it.)  If you *must* install by hand, you'll need to figure out which is the proper directory to install into for each Python, either by exploration and experimentation, or by calling into the same libraries that the installer calls to determine the proper directory.  Installers using `distutils` call `distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib()`; installers using `setup_tools` look in `setup_tools.command.easy_install.easy_install.INSTALL_SCHEMES[os.name]["install_dir"]`.

Regarding `dist-packages`: I had a conversation with the maintainer of the Python package for Debian earlier this year.  He'd implemented this `dist-packages` in the beta packages picked up by Ubuntu 9.04, but the code had a bug wrt `PYTHONUSERBASE` which I tripped over.  We wound up talking a little.  IIRC the reason for `dist-packages` had something to do with forcing the user to install packages in a different directory from *apt-get*.  I clearly don't really understand the motivation, though, because in practice both the user and *apt-get* still install into the same directory.

`lib-dynload` isn't a Debian thing; that's a directory Python itself installs.  I believe it was a directory just for shared libraries implementing modules.  I'm not sure Python still uses it.

Finally, I don't know what you mean by "only python2.6 is actually working".  What about these differently-named directories is "not working"?

Comment: Thanks for explanation Harry, 
But I was asking about installing python itself. It turns out taht when building from source it goes into /usr/local/lib/ by default and when installing with apt-get install it goes into /usr/lib/ and uses the files already present there. I appreciate your example about cleaning up after myself after building other packages, that's a habit I'll start forming.

Comment: I want to see Harry's explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Only python 2.6 is actually working."  Suppose you run the "terminal emulator" and get a command-line prompt.  Is this what you mean:

```
% python -V
Python 2.6
```

In other words, when you run Python, you get version 2.6?  Well, have you tried this:

```
% python2.4
```

If Python 2.4 is correctly installed on your system, it will run.  Likewise `python2.5` will run Python 2.5.

If these don't run, and that is what you meant by "Only python 2.6 is actually working.", then one thing to try is to make sure that you actually have Ubuntu packages installed for Python 2.4 and Python 2.5.

```
% sudo apt-get install python2.4 python2.5
```

If you didn't have them installed before, this should add them.  My thought is that you might have various libraries to support the older versions of Python, but you just don't have the actual Ubuntu packages for those older versions.

Comment: hi steveha,
Thanks for the reply. Yes your explanation is what i meant by "working" and "sudo apt-get install python2.4 python2.5
"got the two python versions installed in /usr/lib/ and put the correct symlinks in /usr/bin/. So now I can use python2.4 and python2.5 to start interpreters and execute .py files.

Comment: So this answered the second part of my question, by explaining how to install python into /usr/lib/. Thanks!